# SQL выборка сообщений

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеется 2 таблицы:

1) messages (id - положительный идентификатор сообщения, from_id - тот кто отправил сообщение, peer_id - получатель сообщения, text - текст сообщения)

2) chats (id - отрицательный идентификатор беседы, name - имя беседы, members_id - массив участников).

Когда пользователь отправляет сообщение, его получатель (peer_id) может быть как пользователем (peer_id = id другого пользователя), так и беседой (peer_id = id беседы). Стоит задача выбрать последние сообщения из всех диалогов данного пользователя (диалог - это либо переписка с пользователем, либо беседа). Создал такой запрос (используется PostgreSql):

```
SELECT m.id AS id, 
       from_id, 
       peer_id, 
       text, 
FROM   messages m 
       LEFT JOIN chats c 
          ON peer_id = c.id 
WHERE  ( @id = from_id 
          OR @id = peer_id 
          OR @id = ANY ( members_id ) ) 
       AND m.id = (SELECT Max(id) 
                   FROM   messages 
                   WHERE  peer_id = c.id 
                           OR from_id = m.from_id 
                              AND peer_id = m.peer_id 
                           OR from_id = m.peer_id 
                              AND peer_id = m.from_id) 
ORDER  BY m.id DESC OFFSET @offset LIMIT @limit
```

@id - пользователь, диалоги которого нужно выбрать. Работает корректно, но как по мне запрос слишком тяжелый, длинный и сложный. Есть ли возможность его упростить или переделать структуру хранения сообщений?

Comment: Меняйте структуру. Получателем ВСЕГДА должна быть беседа (чат). Просто при отправке личного сообщения беседа содержит всего 2 участника.

Comment: А как сохранять ее (Личную беседу)? В таблице chats?

Comment: У тебя есть БЕСЕДА. А два там участника или сто - какая разница?

Comment: Да, я уже понял, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Структура "так себе", но и из неё можно получить необходимый результат :

```
SELECT m.id AS id, 
    from_id, 
    peer_id, 
    text
FROM   messages m 
WHERE
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
        PARTITION BY peer_id
        ORDER BY ID DESC
    ) =1
```

Покурите ранжирующие функции ;)